# Obtaining types through parameters on Java

Tags: java, generics, gson

Certainly I'm quite new in all this Java stuff, so I have a question, I'm trying to deserialize a response obtained on a WCF service, everything works fine, but, I'm trying to make a generic function to do this.

Basically what I do is

```
public List<msg> GetService(String method){
    List<msg> response = new ArrayList<msg>();

    Type msgType = new TypeToken<List<msg>>(){}.getType();

    //Obtaining result
    response = uJSON.fromJson(serviceResponse, msgType);
    //uJSON is an instance of Gson library, for deserializing it just needs
    //the service response and a Class<T> or Type to reflect the obtained message
}
```

What I'm trying to do is obtaining the Type "msg" generic, it means...

```
public <thing> void GetInstanceService(String method){
     List<thing> response = new ArrayList<thing>();

     Type rType2 = new TypeToken<List<thing>>(){}.getType(); //Got java.util.List<thing>

     //And when I'm trying to deserialize I just obtain a List of object 
     //[java.lang.Object@5c7a987e, java.lang.Object@74b1a7a0]

     type2 = uJSON.fromJson(new String(entity), rType2);
}
```

But I'm calling like this.

```
comm.<msgType>GetInstanceService("listTestType");
```

So, when I call "GetInstanceService", "thing" is "msgType" Type, for the 
`List<thing>` and also response shouldn't be `List<msgType>` instead of `List <Object>`?

Besides, when I'm trying to explicitly pass the type through a "Type" parameter, it just causes me compilation time error like this.

```
public void GetInstanceService(Type type){
    List<type> type2 = new ArrayList<type>();  //Compilation time error

    //Or
    msgType oType = new msgType();
    Class classType = oType.getClass();
    List<classType> type3;    //Compilation time error
}
```

So, if none of these attempts was effective, how could I set the type for deserialization?

Comment: Please follow the accepted Java conventions for method names.  `GetInstanceService` should be `getInstanceService`.

Comment: is `thing` a class or an instance?? If it's an instance it cannot be used as the parameter in a parameterized expression.

Comment: and certainly that `type` in `GetInstanceService(Type type)` cannot be used in `new ArrayList<type>()` since it isn't a class...

Comment: yair: thing is a class since I call the method like comm.<msgType>GetInstanceService("listTestType");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guava class [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) does not support that mode of usage. You are creating the type token with a type variable and there not enough information for it to reconstruct `List<String>` from `List<T>`. You should create an instance of `TypeToken` where you have all the required compile-time information.

The documentation says:

> Note that it's critical that the actual type argument is carried by a
>   subclass. The following code is wrong because it only captures the `<T>`
>   type variable of the `listType()` method signature; while `<String>` is
>   lost in erasure:
>
> ```
> class Util {
>   static <T> TypeToken<List<T>> listType() {
>     return new TypeToken<List<T>>() {};
>   }
> }
>
> TypeToken<List<String>> stringListType = Util.<String>listType();
> ```

But as said above, you can instantiate the `TypeToken` at call-site, where all type info are available, and then pass it as a parameter. Something like this:

```
public <thing> void GetInstanceService(String method, TypeToken<List<thing>> token){
     List<thing> response = new ArrayList<thing>();

     Type rType2 = token.getType();

     type2 = uJSON.fromJson(new String(entity), rType2);
}

comm.GetInstanceService("listTestType", new TypeToken<List<msgType>>() {});
```

**Update**

Paul Bellora notes that you can also accept a parameter `TypeToken<thing> token`, and construct a `TypeToken<List<thing>>` inside the method from that `token`:

```
public <thing> void GetInstanceService(String method, TypeToken<thing> token) {
     List<thing> response = new ArrayList<thing>();

     Type rType2 = new TypeToken<List<thing>>() {}
         .where(new TypeParameter<thing>() {}, token); // where() binds "thing" to token
         .getType();

     type2 = uJSON.fromJson(new String(entity), rType2);
}

comm.GetInstanceService("listTestType", new TypeToken<msgType>() {});
```

Comment: Thanks, it work's fine. But I simply can't catch why if I pass as parameter a "Class myClass", I can't just create "List<myClass>". Do you have a clue of it, it's just for knowing that.

Comment: There is a difference in Java between _a class_ and _an object of type `Class`_. Ditto for the difference between _a type_ and _an object of type `Type`_. Examples of classes and types are `int`, `String` and `List<String>`. Examples of `Class` objects and `Type` objects are `int.class`, `String.class` and `new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType()`.

Comment: @No_Name: It is possible to create a `Type` for a generic type with components only known at runtime. You have to implement a class that implements the `ParameterizedType` interface yourself.

Comment: +1 And note that the method could just take a `TypeToken<thing>` and then use [`where`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#where\(com.google.common.reflect.TypeParameter,%20com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken\)) to compose a `TypeToken<List<thing>>`.

Comment: Thanks @PaulBellora, I searched for that method but could not find it :) That [where](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#where(com.google.common.reflect.TypeParameter,%20com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken)) is beautiful API.

Answer (score 2):

Due to something called *type erasure*, the class object you need is not available at runtime.

However, there is a standard work-around: pass a *type token* into your method, like this:

```
public <T> List<T> getService(String method, Class<T> c) {
    // the caller has passed in the class object
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    // fill list
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I just can't catch it. If i pass Class<T> c, I also can't use List<c> and, finally, if I use "c" to deserialize also I got an List of Object, instead of List of msgType. Did I mismatch on something?
-----------
I use
-----------
msgType c =new msgType();...
Class<msgType> classType = (Class<msgType>) c.<msgType>getClass();...
comm.<msgType>getService("listTestType", classType);...
-----
then
-----
List<T> response = new ArrayList<T>();...
response = (List<T>) uJSON.fromJson(new String(entity), c);...
Cause, I can't do
List<c> or ArrayList<c>____
I apologize but editor didn't allow blanks

Comment: And how to construct the `Type` object for `List<T>` from the `Class` object for `T`?